# Building a HR Dataset in T-SQL, would like a row start date column and a row end date column

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, dataset, dimensional-modeling

I have HR dataset problem. For a position, I have position details such as category, type, etc.
These details change over time and independently of each other, resulting in the following datasets:

```
Position    StartDate      EndDate
1           '2020-01-01'   '3000-01-01'

Position    Type        StartDate     EndDate
1           'Part-time' '2020-01-01'  '2020-07-31'
1           'Full-time' '2020-08-01'  '2020-08-30'
1           'Part-time' '2020-09-01'  '3000-01-01

Position    Category      StartDate     EndDate
1           'Agency'      '2020-01-01'  '2020-06-30'
1           'Employee'    '2020-07-01'  '2020-08-30'
1           'Contractor'  '2020-09-01'  '3000-01-01
```

So from this, I would like to get a dataset such as:

```
Position   Type         Category      StartDate      EndDate
1          'Part-time'  'Agency'      '2020-01-01'   '2020-06-30'
1          'Part-time'  'Employee'    '2020-07-01'   '2020-07-31'
1          'Full-time'  'Employee'    '2020-08-01'   '2020-08-30'
1          'Part-time'  'Contractor'  '2020-09-01'   '3000-01-01'
```

So that when filtered on a date, it will bring back the situation for that position on that date. For this example on '2020-07-05', the position will show as a part-time employee.

Methods I've looked at so far include CASE statements for creating the StartDate and EndDate fields

And creating a union of the datasets, and running ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Position OVER BY StartDate, EndDate) to try to filter out the wrong rows when these tables are joined.

Edit: Apologies, I should have added, this is the minimum example of the problem. The example I'm looking at will have 6-12 columns. So the solution will need to be scalable.

Comment: Why do you need the last dataset you have listed? If you just want to know the situation for a position on a date, what is this issue with just querying the first 3 tables?

Comment: For reporting purposes, this table would be joined into the item being measured as a dimension table.

Comment: Hi - I could understand you wanting to build this type of table if you were designing a Kimball-style star schema but the table as you describe it is not a Kimball Dimension and therefore, I assume, you are not actually building a star schema? I therefore, still, think that it would be much easier to just query your existing tables when you want to report on them, rather than trying to construct this intermediary table that is providing little additional benefit

Answer (score 0):

The method I'd choose is to apply a CROSS JOIN between the Types and the Categories table with filtering by overlapping phases of both tables.

```
SELECT * FROM Position p
INNER JOIN Type t
    ON t.Position = p.Position
CROSS JOIN Category c
WHERE c.StartDate >= t.StartDate AND c.StartDate <= t.EndDate
    OR (t.StartDate >= c.StartDate AND t.StartDate <= c.EndDate)
    OR (c.StartDate < t.StartDate AND c.EndDate > t.EndDate)
ORDER BY t.StartDate
```

In the SELECT list you can apply your CASE Statement to choose the right date for your date range.

Comment: You might be onto something. Adding in a table at a time and calculating intermediate datasets will be where I look at next. I've just clarified my original problem submission, but the cross joining and filtering will be difficult/intensive once the problem is scaled to ~6000 employees across multiple years and multiple attributes (columns).